# Formally showing a function has a pole of order $1$. (or any other order)

Tags: complex-analysis

I was in the process of finding the value of $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{1/4x}}{1+e^x}dx$$ Obviously it needs to use residue theorem, and it's not a problem to find it. But I got a question how do we formally show that a function has a pole of order $n$? In this case, the function $$f(z)=\frac{e^{1/4z}}{1+e^z}$$ has a pole at $z=\pi i$.

So suppose the function $f(z)$ has a pole of order $n>1$ at $z=\pi i$. Then, by definition, we can write $$f(z)=\frac{h_{1}}{z-\pi i}+\frac{h_{2}}{(z-\pi i)^2}+...+\frac{h_{n}}{(z-\pi i)^n}+g(z)$$ where $h_k$ and $g(z)$ are holomorphic. Then, we can multiply both sides by $(z-\pi i)^n$, so we have $$\frac{e^{1/4z}(z-\pi i)^n}{1+e^z}=h_1(z-\pi i)^{n-1}+h_2(z-\pi i)^{n-2}+...+h_n+g(z)(z-\pi i)^n$$
I want to draw a conclusion continuing this process, but trying to differentiate both sides $n-1$ times doesn't seem like a very clever way to show that the function actually blows up. Can anyone pick up and show me how to proceed this formally?

Edit: I just want to clarify that the integration is not a problem here. It's just a random function that was in front of me, I'm using as an example. I was looking to formally show any given function has a pole of order $n$. I'm just mentioning this because it looks like the majority of comments and previous answer that was deleted only concerns about how to proceed and solving this integration.

Comment: $1+e^z$ has a zero of order $1$ at $\pi i$ since its derivative is nonzero there.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio The integral converges to $\pi\sqrt{2}$. Consider a rectangular contour with bottom edge on the real line, and upper edge on $2\pi i$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio It all depends on whether $1/4x$ is $1/(4x)$ or $(1/4)x$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio it is the latter. $\frac{1}{4}x$. I was being lazy typing. I should have made that clear.